# Positional and Keyword markers / * syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading the syntax for positional and keyword argument inputs and ran into an error where using the `/` and `*` markers results in a syntax error.

I was following [a tutorial for Python arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) on

Please refer to: 4.7.3.4. Function Examples:

```
def pos_only_arg(arg, /):
    print(arg)

pos_only_arg(1)
pos_only_arg(arg = 1)
```

The first output `pos_only_arg` should output 1 and the second should throw an error. However, even `pos_only_arg(1)` results in a syntax error

Answer (score 2):

Are you running [version 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters) or newer? If not, you need to update your python version for this to work.

Enter `python --version` on the command line and see if it's <3.8.